# How to use the same JQuery effect for different divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I'm not really into using javascript and jQuery so please add detailed answers.

I need to add a jQuery effect to different `div`s with the same class, so that when I click on a div `1` with class `item`, another div `info` will appear in a specific container.
Also, if I click on div `2` with the same class `item`, another div `pics` will appear in the same container as `info` while `info` will disappear.

I was going to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").click(function(){
        $("#box1").fadeOut(250);
    });
    $("#box1").click(function(){
        $("#box2").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

But this is not valid for using about 10 `div`s and another 10 displaying and hiding `div`s.
I would use many lines of code and I am not sure that it would work.

Comment: Show us an example of your html.  We can get you pointed in the right direction much easier, then.

Comment: Store the element in a variable to save a lot of time.

Comment: You have to call and understand Jquery selectors.

Comment: please post you html code so we can understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the selector `$(".item")` to get all the `div`s you're interested in.

Class selector sounds like what you need: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

You can differentiate the ids once you're inside the click call and take a different action. but the class selector will let you use the click event handler on all of the divs you're interested in.

sample code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(e){
        // output the id of the clicked item
        console.log($(e.target).attr("id"));

        if($(e.target).attr("id")=="box1"){
            //do something for if the clicked item is box1.
            $("#box1").fadeOut(250);
            $("#box2").fadeIn(500);            
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your html, it's hard to say exactly.  But, here's a starter point.

Your existing jQuery is like so, which is grabbing every div by ID.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").click(function(){
        $("#box1").fadeOut(250);
    });
    $("#box1").click(function(){
        $("#box2").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

An improvement would be to use a *class* rather than an ID, and you could do something like so.

**NOTE:** The below assumes you assign either a different class, or an additional class of `itempic` to the div(s) you want to trigger the pics to be displayed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        $(".info").fadeOut(250);
    });
    $(".itempic").click(function(){
        $(".pics").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

If you have multiple divs that are going to have this same functionality (for example, you've got a bunch of products, each with an info box and a pic box), then you'll need to do something with "containing" the selectors to the given items.  With some example HTML, I could provide an answer that takes that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Structure you html similar to this

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="info">info contents</div>
   <div id="pic">pic contents</div>
</div>

<div class="item" data-related="#info">your contents</div>
<div class="item" data-related="#pic">your contents</div>
..etc.
```

and use

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').children().hide(); // initial hiding 

    $('.item').click(function(){
        var relatedId = $(this).data('related');
        $(relatedId).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mTSZv/

Comment: Your solution seems to be the best but It didn't work for me !!
I did exactly what you have done and it didn't work !! Note: I've put the text in the divs with class "item" inside an <a> tag and arranged the "item" divs in a "ul" list..

Answer (score 0):

When selecting with jQuery you need to use #id_name for IDs and .class_name for classes. When selecting div, tr, td, ... you need no special symbol before the name. So:

```
$('#id_name').click(); // click on every item of the ID 'id_name'
$('.class_name').hide(); // make all items invisible that have class 'class_name'
$('tr').addClass('class_name'); // adds the class 'class_name' to all tr items
```

IDs are unique. Classes can appear more than once.

Just read the examples on [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

In order to get started with JS jQuery is very good. Very fast to do, but don't forget jQuery is a library that has to be loaded making these short commands possible. Pure javascript will be faster.
Don't forget, you can combine JS and jQuery, as jQuery is JS. Switching to pure JS will also make you see what your scripts exactly do.